# hangouts not syncing from PC to Nexus 6

Tags: google-hangouts

I have the hangouts extension installed in chrome on windows 7 and windows 8 PCs and a stock Nexus 6 which has hangouts installed as a system app. When I send and receive messages on my PCs my phone doesn't update with those messages sent on the PC. I also have a Nexus 7 on lollipop and it syncs messages just fine. My LG G3 also syncs messages. I have tried wiping cache/data in the app, signing in and out of chrome and the google account on my phone, factory resetting the phone, etc.

Anyone have any ideas? I tend to switch between my phone and PC all the time and would live to be able to have synced conversations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GCM Push Notifications don't work with IPv6. I disabled IPv6 entirely in my router and now everything is fine. Though IPv6 was enabled for the past two years and I didn't have any kind of issue. Let's hope a Play Services update fixes it.

[Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/push-notifications-not-working-over-wifi-on-google-devices) is where I got the answer. On rooted devices, you can install [[ROOT] Disable IPv6](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lennartschoch.disableipv6) to fix the problem.